# Facing problem to validate user in ClientPeoplePicker using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

I added 3 users in ClientPeoplePicker but when i am removing 1 or 2 users and saving the ClientPeoplePicker values. Still saving all 3 users. How to handle these removed users from ClientPeoplePicker? Can you suggest me.

Comment: share some of your code please

Answer (score 1):

you can add validation to allow only **one person** to the people picker by using the following code in the submission button

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnsubmit").on("click", function(a) {
        if ($("#txtName").find('div.sp-peoplepicker-topLevel').find('.sp-peoplepicker-resolveList').children().length != 1) {
            alert("Please enter only one name");
            initializePeoplePicker("txtName"); //Reinitialise people picker again
        } else{
           saving code
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Code:

```
var usr;
var contextDR;
var webDR;
var teamleaderarray = new Array();
$(document).ready(function ()  {
     initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerteamleaderDiv');
     SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getusername); 
});

//initialize PeoplePicker div tag 
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId)  {
     var schema = {};
     schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
     schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
     schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
     schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
     schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
     schema['Width'] = '222px'; 
     this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}

function getUserInfo1()  
{
     teamleaderarray = [];
     var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerteamleaderDiv_TopSpan;
     var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
     var userInfo = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)     
     {
        var user = users[i];
        teamleaderarray.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(user["Description"]));            
     }
}

function btnSave_Click() {

    //get users from peoplepicker 
        getUserInfo1();

    //create clientcontext object and create web object     
        contextDR = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        webDR = contextDR.get_web();
        contextDR.load(webDR);

    //get list
        var Lst = webDR.get_lists().getByTitle('listname');
        contextDR.load(Lst);        
   //create new item in list    
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        InListItem = Lst.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        InListItem.set_item('Auditleader', teamleaderarray);                
        InListItem.update();    
        contextDR.load(InListItem);      
        contextDR.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.submitsuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.submitfail)); 
}
```

body part:

```
<div id="peoplePickerteamleaderDiv"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" onclick="javascript: btnSave_Click();" />
```

use this js reference:

```
_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js
_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js
_layouts/15/clientforms.js
_layouts/15/autofill.js
_layouts/15/1033/strings.js
```

Using this code my peoplepicker run perfectly,

if any problem add comment.